# css not working when uploading laravel to shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, backend

CSS not working when uploading laravel to shared hosting,
I've set all the files correctly the server.php and so on, also I did PHP artisan generate, and it's not working too, I have pure HTML only without CSS, maybe I did not change important file settings, or might be a way to run laravel without PHP artisan serv.

Notice ( im not using php artisan on server that wont work im asking if the way im doing it is right)

Comment: you don't use `artisan serve` that is a local development server ... your shared hosting is a webserver, that is the point of hosting

Comment: Im not using php artisan im asking the way im doing it right or not, and the css still wont lod

Comment: can you provide further debugging details? it is pretty hard to determine the issue without seeing anything

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To all of you who tried to help,
To all who have this issue, you have to make the root folder public if you have changed the config/app.php it wont work.